# Mvc5 Select2 load results via ajax based on searchTerm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’m trying to use Select2 and load data with ajax based on search term. I looked so many examples, but I just can’t figure it out what am I missing.

I added select2.css and select.js and included them in the layout view.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/select2.css")" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is in the view which displays textbox for search:

```
// Not sure what here should be also.
<input id="productSelect" style="width:200px" />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#productSelect).select2({
            placeholder: 'Select a product',
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchProducts", "Product")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
}
```

This is the method in the controller:

```
public JsonResult SearchProducts(string searchTerm)
        {
            var products = Db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
            var result = products.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, text = p.Name });
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The textbox is not showing data or searching anything. Can someone, please, explain how it should be done correctly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

select2 dropdowns work like search box too. So, typically you do not need `<input id="productSelect" style="width:200px" />` as input. Instead, do these:

1. Create the `<select>` tag

```html
<select id="productSelect">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Search for product...</option>
</select>
```

2. Set up the script

```js
$("#productSelect").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchProducts", "Product")',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (term) {
      return {
        searchTerm: term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

3. If you need the data to be loaded in batches, giving an illusion of infinite scrolling, then modify your controller to return a JSON `data` with two parameters: the batch (I called it `Items`) and total count (I called it `TotalCount`). Your script will then look like this:

```js
$("#productSelect").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchProducts", "Product")',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      return {
        searchTerm: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page, // 1-based page indexing
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      return {
          results: data.Items,
          pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.TotalCount
          }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```